# Transformations of random variables in the form of polynomials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to find the probability density function (pdf) of $F$. $F$ is the polynomial of three independent random variables $X, Y, Z$ , where $$F = aX+bY+cZ+dX^2+eY^2+fZ^2+gXY+hYZ+iXZ, $$ and $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i$ are constants. We know that the random variables $X, Y, Z$ are independent and each of them satisfies Gaussian distribution. I do not know how to derive the pdf of $F$. If there are general solutions to this kind of problem? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there is a closed form solution, it is probably extremely ugly. Perhaps start by trying to find the distribution of $aX + bY + dX^2+eY^2+gXY$?

Comment: $X, Y, Z$ are mutual independence. So they are jointly gaussian

Comment: @Michael.Andy yes, I've read too quickly  .

Comment: If you assume that 
$F=(\sqrt{d}X+\sqrt{e}Y+\sqrt{f}Z)^2+(aX+bY+cZ)$
(where the other coefficients $g,h,i$ are defined to satisfy the equality) you have the sum of a square of a gaussian random variable, that can be standarized so to obtain a chi square,an a gaussian random variable. I don't know if there's some closed form though-

Comment: Thank you RScrlli. The chi square random variable and the gauss random vairiable are not independent. I do not konw how to derive the pdf of the sum of them, even they are independent.

Comment: @Michael.Andy indeed, it seems like a very complicated task.

Answer (score 1):

If your polynomial was  $p(x,y,z)= a_{11}x^2 + a_{22}y^2 + a_{33}z^2 + (2a_{12})xy + (2a_{13})xz + (2a_{23})yz$, then
$$ p(x,y,z) = (X,Y,Z) A(X,Y,Z)^T $$
where $A=((a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq 3})$. Since $A$ is symmetric, its eigenvalues are real and the eigenvectors are orthogonal, i.e.
$$ A = V\Lambda V^T $$
where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, and $V\in O(3)$. Let $(X,Y,Z)^T = V (\xi,\eta,\zeta)^T $, then
$$ (X,Y,Z)A(X,Y,Z)^T= (\xi,\eta,\zeta) V^T  A V (\xi,\eta,\zeta)^T = (\xi,\eta,\zeta) \Lambda (\xi,\eta,\zeta)^T = \lambda_1 \xi^2 + \lambda_2\eta^2 + \lambda_3 \zeta^2 . $$
Now since $V$ is orthogonal $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)\sim N(0,I)$. Hence the distribution of $p(X,Y,Z)$ is some generalized version of $\chi^2$.

Now if $p(x,y,z)$ is a general bivariate polynomial of degree $2$, then it is possible to write it in the form
$$ p(x,y,z)= (x-a,y-b,z-c) A (x-a,x-b,z-c)^T +d  $$
where $a,b,c,d$ are appropriate constants and $A$ is an appropriate $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix. Since $(X-a,Y-b,Z-c)\sim N((-a,-b,-c), I) $ the closest one can say about the distribution of $p(X,Y,Z)$ is that it is some generalized version of $\chi^2$ with shift $d$.

Update: The above derivation assumed that $(X,Y,Z)$ is a standard Gaussian vector, i.e. its mean is the zero vector and its covariance matrix is $I$, the identity matrix. In case $(X,Y,Z)\sim N(\mu, diag(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2,\sigma_3^2))$ then $diag(1/\sigma_1,1/\sigma_2,1/\sigma_3)\cdot (X-\mu_1,Y-\mu_2,Z-\mu_3) \sim N(0,I) $.

Comment: Thank you Mick! I follow the method you provide here and I have some questions. I find that $(X, Y, Z)A(X,Y, Z)^T = (\xi, \eta, \zeta)VAV^T(\xi, \eta, \zeta)^T,$ which is different from the above answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's a typo, corrected it.

Comment: However, $VAV^T$ is not equal to $\Lambda$, which hinders the following derivation.

Comment: But $V^T A V$ does, it was a typo, that's been taken care of. Please check the updated answer

Comment: I got it. Does $I$ mean that the variances of $\xi, \eta, \zeta$ are all 1? Actually, $X, Y, Z$ are independent with the same mean 0 but different variances. Will the derivation remain the same?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I try to use the distribution function to obtain closed-form pdf of this kind of generalized $\chi^2$ but I can not derive the pdf from the triple integral. I have tried the spherical coordinate conversion method but failed. Could you give me some advice？Thank you！

Comment: Well I'm not sure that there exists some nice form of the pdf... If the variances are all equal then it' basically a rescaled Gamma distribution, but with different variances it's a lo uglier I'm pretty sure...

Comment: Can the distribution with different variance be approximated by three rescaled Gamma distributions? For example, use the distribution of $\lambda_1(\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2),\lambda_2(\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2), \lambda_3(\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2)$to approximate the distribution of $\lambda_1\xi^2+\lambda_2\eta^2+\lambda_3\zeta^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105729/discussion-between-michael-andy-and-mick).

Comment: okay let's do that.

Comment: Hello Mick! Your answer is helpful and I want to invite you to be my co-author in my manuscript.

Comment: thank you, I'd participate gladly!

Comment: How can I contact with you?

Comment: Let me know your email address and I'll contact you.

Comment: My email address: michaelandy_shen@163.com